# Would adding Google event tracking code break a button?

Tags: javascript

My old code looked like this-

```
input type="button" name="ctl00$MainContent$PlaceBidButton" 
value="" onclick="this.disabled = true;__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$PlaceBidButton','')" 
id="MainContent_PlaceBidButton" class="place_bid" style="height:22px;width:82px;"
```

My new code looks like this-

```
input type="button" name="ctl00$MainContent$PlaceBidButton" 
value=""
onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','PlaceOffer','Submitted']);this.disabled = true;__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$PlaceBidButton','')" 
id="MainContent_PlaceBidButton" class="place_bid" style="height:22px;width:82px;"
```

The event seems to have stopped happening since I put this code on. Could adding the code `javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','PlaceOffer','Submitted'])` possibly have broken the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the

```
javascript:
```

at the beginning of the onclick call. This might be source of your problem.

Comment: I will try that on tomorrow morning, I currently do not have access to the code. I am a novice coder, do you have any explanation as to why the javascript: would cause a problem?

Comment: @TylerJensen The reason is because you should only include valid JavaScript code in the onclick. `javascript:` is not valid JavaScript. It is used to declare what follows should be interpreted as JavaScript. It's used primarily in browser address bars or possibly hyperlinks, never in the context you are using it for here.

Comment: I am now running a bunch of tests and it works for me every time. I have tried it in IE, Firefox, and Chrome. I am now wondering if the button actually works and Google is recording false information. Does that seem possible?

Comment: It may take a while for Google to register the changes so that you see them.